# Does using pixels for the root font size discard user preferences?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I want to use rem for my font-size, so the user can have a scalable font-size for the paragraphs through his browser settings. I chose fontsize=10px for the root, for easy coversion of the photoshop font-sizes.  Does using pixels for the root font size discard user preferences? Do I have to set the root element in percentage oder in pixels?

```
html {
  font-size: font-size: 10px;;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.2rem; /* will be 12px
}
```

Comment: note that this will be *way* too small to read on most screens, thanks to modern high-dpi displays in cellphones/tablets, as well as high resolution monitors for deskop/laptops. Also remember a *vast* part of the earth's population has less than perfect vision. Consider the browser's 16px default size a soft minimum: if you find you need to go below that, that's a good sign you need to rethink your styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does using pixels for the root font size discard user preferences?

Yes, it discards the base font size preference specifically. The font size will still be affected by browser zoom, but that is a separate thing entirely.

Browsers usually ship with a default preferred font size of 16px. If you want your base font size to be 10px, but still allow for scaling based on the user's preferred font size, you can set the root font size to 62.5%.